# How to append data to a existing pdf file using iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, report, itext

Data is dynamically genarated, i want to write(append to the end of file) this data to a pdf file without loosing the previous data.

Comment: *append to the **end of file*** - do you mean **starting on a new page** or do you mean somehow **after the last content of the current last page**?

Comment: Last content of the current page

Comment: You can start by creating the new text in a new PDF and then using the dense merge tool from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28024276/1729265) or the very dense merge tool from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265).

Comment: Thanks,For each time when the script is run, it should check first existing file is created or not. If existing file is created, it should write the data at the end of the file without loosing the old data for the previous run.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :-

1. Example [http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123 ]
2. Example [[Appending a data in itext in existing pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597259/appending-a-data-in-itext-in-existing-pdf) ]

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there is other way we can append data to the pdf file without creating a copy