# Generate PDF version 1.4 from rdlc local file

Tags: .net, pdf, rdlc

I have several reports (.rdlc files) in the project.  I need to generate PDF files from these reports, but I need PDF version 1.4 or higher.

Currently I am using the report.Render method to generate a PDF, but the version generated is 1.3.  As far as I can tell there is no option to generate a newer version.

Environment:
Visual Studio 2010
Windows Forms Application
C#
.NET Framework 4
Report Viewer 2010

Comment: Could you please explain *why* you need a v1.4 PDF? To me a PDF is a PDF. If it's got your report in it, who cares what version it is?

Comment: The company who is receiving the PDF requires v1.4.  I don't understand it either.

Answer (score 0):

Check out itextsharp.dll http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ it can write to 1.4 there is also documentation in the download to configure it.

Comment: I looked at iTextSharp.  It would work if I was generating a PDF from scratch, but I can't find any way to use it with an .rdlc file.

Comment: @300hp Couldn't you open it and save it again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335126/itext-add-content-to-existing-pdf-file