# How to add header image in pdf report generated from database using itext

Tags: pdf, servlets, header, itext

Hii Guys !!
             Below is my code to export database into excel file .Now as per my requirement i want to add header image of company at the top of the page .plz guys help me and guide me to complete the task.thanks in advance .below is my code...

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:/".concat(datum1).concat(" ").concat("To").concat(" ").concat(datum2).concat(".pdf")));
        document.open();

        Image logo = Image.getInstance("d:/header.png");
        logo.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
        logo.scaleAbsoluteHeight(20);
        logo.scaleAbsoluteWidth(20);
        logo.scalePercent(100);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(logo, 0, -45);
        HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(chunk), false);
        header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        document.setHeader(header);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
        table.setWidthPercentage(110);
        table.addCell("calldate");
        table.addCell("src");
        table.addCell("dst");
        table.addCell("dstchannel");
        table.addCell("lastapp");
        table.addCell("duration");
        table.addCell("disposition");
        table.addCell("amaflags");
        table.addCell("cdrcost");


        String strQuery = "";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        conexion conexiondb = new conexion();
        conexiondb.Conectar();

        strQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdrcost where date(calldate) between '" + datum1 + "' and '" + datum2 + "'";

        // strQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdrcost where date(calldate) between '2011-09-01' and '2012-01-01'";

        rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);
        while (rs.next()) {
            table.addCell(rs.getString("calldate"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("src"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("dst"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("dstchannel"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("lastapp"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("duration"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("disposition"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("amaflags"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("cdrcost"));
        }

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
```

Comment: Duplicate question, answered yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465657/itext-add-content-to-the-bottom-of-an-existing-page

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Sir i went through the link but did not solved my issue plz sir help me

Answer (score 0):

1. As explained in [add content to the bottom of an existing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465657/itext-add-content-to-the-bottom-of-an-existing-page), the method `setHeader()` has been removed from iText a long time ago. Please don't use it!
2. You can easily add an image as a header by using page events. Page events are explained in [Chapter 5 of iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book). You can find references to examples on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465657/itext-add-content-to-the-bottom-of-an-existing-page)

As you don't seem to understand the answer given previously on SO, let me repeat:

You need to create a `PdfPageEvent` implementation, for instance by extending the `PdfPageEventHelper` class overriding the `onEndPage()` method. When you do so, take into account the following caveats:

- Do not use `onStartPage()` to add content,
- Do not add anything to the `Document` object passed to the page event,
- Unless you specified a different page size, the lower-left corner has the coordinate `x = 0; y = 0`. You need to take that into account when adding the footer. The y-value for the footer is lower than the y-value for the header.

In your code, you need to use the `setPageEvent()` method on the `PdfWriter` object *before* opening the document. Every time a page is finished the `onEndPage()` method you wrote will be called, so that's where you need to add the image using `PdfContentByte.addImage()`. If you want the image to be on the top of the page, you need to ask the `Document` for its dimensions, and set the absolute position for the Image object accordingly.

If you don't understand this elaborate explanation, please read my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book) or hire an iText developer to do this assignment for you.